# T-test for grouped data in R commander

Tags: r, r-commander

I've the following data format

```
Entity Measure1 Measure2
A1     1.5      1.4
A1     1.9      1.7
A1     1.8      1.5
B1     2.7      2.5
B1     3.0      2.9
B1     3.1      2.7
B1     2.8      2.9
C1     1.7      1.5
C1     1.7      1.8
...
```

I wish to do a pairwise T-test for the `Entity` factor and at `Measure1` and `Measure2` levels. I can do this in R but is there any way to do in R Commander GUI? In R Commander the paired t-test considers all the values of `Measure1` and `Measure2` columns and doesn't perform the t-test groupwise. The 'independent sample t-test' option is grayed out too.

Comment: Multiple pairwise t-tests by group is really repeated measures ANOVA.

Answer (score 3):

If you abandoned the paired-t.test formalism you could do this with regression:

```
 lm( Measure2 ~ Measure1 + Entity, data=dfrm)
```

This will give you an estimate of mean increase in Measure2 (from Measure 1) by group. Thats eally what paired t-tests are doing, anyway.